# how to access neo4j server with only one port

Tags: nginx, neo4j, port

We're using neo4j **server 3.1.4**

We want to deploy neo4j server behind nginx, and our environment just allow one port:80 for nginx.

But neo4j browser need **HTTP port**(default 7474), and **bolt port**(default 7687).
So we config nginx to access HTTP port, we failed to connect bolt port.
It reported WebSocket connection error, for we can't access another port.

We checked the neo4j.conf & documentation,and found no useful information.

So, Is there any way to **access neo4j server with only one port**(80)? 
Can anyone help us with this situation?

[screen errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOKyV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j browser is just a client for the database, and in a prod env, I never give access to it by the outside.

So in your case, I will just map the bolt port to the 80 one on nginx.

And if you want access to Neo4j with a browser, you should consider to use the Neo4j Desktop application, and configure a remote database.

Comment: Thank you very much!  you's right, we don't allow access from outside.

Comment: We'll try to use neo4j desktop & bolt port.